# How to process array items given in YAML to associate with a struct in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, struct, yaml

I have not found a way to allocate values defined in an array within a YAML file field to the fields of a struct in Go. I am already unmarshalling the whole file to a defined struct, but I would like to go deeper.

The YAML file is a hardcoded file.

YAML File

```
- id : [apples,bananas]
  fruits: true
  vegetables: false

- id : [apples,onions]
  fruits: true
  vegetables: true
```

Go structs

```
type Basket struct {
    ID RawID `yaml:"id"`
    Content BasketContent
}

type RawID struct {
       Apples  bool `yaml:"apples"`
       Bananas bool `yaml:"bananas"`
       Onions  bool `yaml:"onions"`
}

type BasketContent struct {
    Fruits     boolean `yaml:"fruits"`
    Vegetables boolean `yaml:"vegetables"`
}
```

I am expecting to identify which elements are located in the id field, to later hash them into a value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following package that has definitions of yaml to structs

https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

This includes documentation on how to handle arrays.

**Edit 1: Including relevant code snippet**

```
var data = `
a: Easy!
b:
  c: 2
  d: [3, 4]
`

// Note: struct fields must be public in order for unmarshal to
// correctly populate the data.
type T struct {
        A string
        B struct {
                RenamedC int   `yaml:"c"`
                D        []int `yaml:",flow"`
        }
}
```